# Connect laravel 5 to AWS RDS with SSL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ssl, amazon-rds

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741546/enviroment-specific-ssl-config-in-laravel-env-file) and [this article](https://www.thirdandgrove.com/how-to-encrypt-database-connection-in-laravel-on-heroku-with-cleardb-without-putting-ssl-certifications-or-keys-in-source-control).

```
'your_connection' => array(
  'driver'  => 'mysql',
  'host'    => $host,
  'database'  => $database,
  'username'  => $username,
  'password'  => $password,
  'charset'   => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix'  => '',
  'options' => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => $cert_base . '/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => $cert_base . '/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => $cert_base . '/ca-cert.pem'
  ),
),
```

From what I understand, `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA`, is can be downloaded from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem)

I am not sure `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY` and `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT`

I read something like [this](http://xmodulo.com/enable-ssl-mysql-server-client.html)

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
openssl req -sha1 -new -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -key ca-key.pem > ca-cert.pem
```

It seems that is what I need to do, could anyone confirm?

Answer (score 10):

To connect to AWS RDS via SSL in Laravel you only need to do a few things.

Download the rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem file from:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

Then place it in your configuration like this:

```
'options' => array(    
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => $cert_base . '/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'
 ),
```

It doesn't require the other two keys to connect.

Comment: But not work in my case

Comment: **PDO::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed at /home/ubuntu/project_dir/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:40**

Comment: **facing this error**

Comment: **while connecting with RDS cluster @aws**

Comment: **While connecting with RDS proxy endpoint**

Comment: **What will be for RDS cluster** 
General error: 3159 Database Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON

Answer (score 0):

**`RDS Proxy and cluster endpoint SSL connection with Laravel 7 application`**
Download pem from the following link
https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem

**1. Add the below line of code into your database config php file**

```
 'options' => [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => base_path('AmazonRootCA1.pem')
        ],
```

**2. I have enabled SSL on RDS Cluster by using the following link**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql-ssl-connections.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

**3. Enabled `Transport Layer Security` by updating proxy configuration**